# Как подогнать размер изображения под размер контейнера, если размеры их неизвестны?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, angularjs

Использую Bootstrap 3, [Angular-gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster).
Необходимо сделать блок с заголовком и контентом, аналогично `panel` с `panel-heading` и `panel-content` в Bootstrap 3.
Размеры заранее неизвестны. 
Причем в каждом `panel-content` располагается изображение, значительно большее по размеру, чем родительский контейнер (panel). Обрезать изображение не нужно, нужно пропорционально его масштабировать, если остается пустое место - ок.
Для подгонки размера изображения пытаюсь использовать класс `img-responsive`, однако конечный размер контейнера panel искажается (увеличивается его высота, в итоге высота panel больше, чем высота `li`; поэтому происходит наложение блоков `li` друг на друга)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
    <ul>
        <li gridster-item="block" ng-repeat="block in blocks"  data-row="block.position[0]" data-col="block.position[1]">
            <div class="panel panel-default">              
                   <div class="panel-heading">
                        {{ block.title }}
                   </div>                       
                   <div class="panel-content">   
                        <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="/media/{{ block.image }}">                                    
                   </div>
             </div>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Если я убираю изображение из контейнера `panel-content`, высота `panel` соответствуют высоте `li`. Т.е. видимо проблема в использовании `.img-responsive` внутри `.panel`.

Текущие настройки `angular-gridster`:

```
resizable: {
    enabled: false
},
columns: 10,
margins: [0, 0],
outerMargin: false
```

Идеи по поводу решения:

- использовать вместо `img` `background`, но как тогда растянуть `div`
  или другой контейнер, у которого устанавливается фон?
- использовать таблицы или `display: table, display: table-cell` ?
- изменить настройки `angular-gridster`?
- делать [ресайз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261677/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-div?rq=1) при помощи `javascript`/`jQuery`? Пробовал этот вариант, непонятно, когда вызывать функцию ресайзинга, т.к. блоки подгружаются не в момент `document.ready()`
- Также пробовал [такой вариант](https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/dashboard), для того, чтобы не использовать `Bootstrap`, однако как в этом случае масштабировать изображение? И как лучше его расположить - в виде `img` или `background`?
  Получилось практически подогнать размер вот так:
  у `div class="box-content"`:

  ```
       overflow: auto;

       background: url(путь к изображению) no-repeat center center transparent;

       background-size: cover; //или contain

       height: 100%;
  ```

Однако все равно блоки немного налезают друг на друга.

- Также вместо класса `img-responsive` использовал `img-thumbnail`, разница в высотах уменьшилась, но все равно присутствует.

Или все же есть вариант решения с `Bootstrap`?

**Обновление:**
Добавил [пример кода](http://jsfiddle.net/e1jvagkq/9/) Вот здесь вроде все так, как у меня сейчас, у картинок только почему-то не генерируется `src` из `ng-src`, поэтому они не подгружаются. Блоки передвигаются.

**Пояснение:**
Заголовок увеличивает высоту. В момент перетаскивания angular-gridster выделяет область, куда можно перетащить блок, и весь блок, который перетаскивается (panel), по высоте больше, чем эта область, на высоту заголовка (panel-heading). Это происходит только в случае использования картинок в panel-content, сам заголовок проблемы с высотой блока не создает. Если я правильно понимаю, либо высота блока на основе sizeY неправильно рассчитывается, что менее вероятно, либо высота panel-content (вернее, картинки внутри)

Comment: приведите пример кода на http://jsfiddle.net, а то непонятно как и почему они "налазят"

Comment: @Neka попытался, но выдает ошибку, не могу разобраться http://jsfiddle.net/mdlv/e1jvagkq/

Comment: Проблему с подключением скриптов исправил: http://jsfiddle.net/e1jvagkq/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e1jvagkq/9/ Вот здесь вроде все так, как у меня сейчас, у картинок только почему-то не генерируется src из ng-src, поэтому они не подгружаются. Блоки передвигаются.

Comment: Ширина `li`, определяется относительно ширины экрана параметром `sizeX`, он же используется для определения и резервирования места при перемещении `li`.  Чтобы блоки не наезжали друг на друга, нужно определить длину `.panel-heading` и если она больше текущей ширины `li`, то увеличить значение `sizeX` у этого `id`.

вот как-то так.

Comment: @Neka проблема как раз не с шириной, а с высотой, т.к. заголовок увеличивает высоту. В момент перетаскивания angular-gridster выделяет область, куда можно перетащить блок, и весь блок, который перетаскивается (panel), по высоте больше, чем эта область, на высоту заголовка (panel-heading). Это происходит только в случае использования картинок в panel-content, сам заголовок проблемы с высотой блока не создает. Если я правильно понимаю, либо размер sizeY неправильно рассчитывается, что менее вероятно, либо размер panel-content (вернее, картинки внутри)

Comment: @Emm без картинок, только проблемы шапки видны (из за того что слово не влазит), а без картинок (мне) невидно проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел на ваш fiddle, пришёл с таким решением: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/qqzvjvfx/5/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{ block.title }}</div>
    <div class="panel-content image-responsive" 
         ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + block.image + ')'}"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.panel .panel-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-responsive {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

Некоторые пункты:

- Не причина проблемы, но вам не хватает `jquery.resize.js`, который нужен для `angular-gridster` если размер решётки меняет (см. [readme](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster))
- Использую flexbox, т.е. про Internet Explorer < 10 нужно забывать

Comment: большое спасибо, все работает. Но обнаружилась одна проблема - при масштабировании страницы в браузере масштаб не применяется к изображениям внутри блоков.

Comment: вот в этом примере масштабирование работает https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/main правда, там не используется `flexbox`

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так

```
.panel-content:after, .panel-content:before{
display:table;
content:" ";
clear:both;
}
```

Не будет вылезать за `li`

Comment: не помогло, блоки точно так же себя ведут

Comment: Как ведут? как на картинке panel-heading что ли на верхнего залезает?

Comment: как на картинке, нижний блок (panel) перекрывает частично верхний

Comment: для panel-heading тоже  добавь .panel-heading:after, .panel-heading:before{
display:table;
content:" ";
clear:both;
}

Comment: сделал так, теперь немного по-другому накладываются друг на друга: http://s017.radikal.ru/i426/1510/db/fde57a19d1ac.png

Comment: Заголовок увеличивает высоту. В момент перетаскивания angular-gridster выделяет область, куда можно перетащить блок, и весь блок, который перетаскивается (panel), по высоте больше, чем эта область, на высоту заголовка (panel-heading). Это происходит только в случае использования картинок в panel-content, сам заголовок проблемы с высотой блока не создает. Если правильно понимаю, неправильно рассчитывается высота panel-content (вернее, картинки внутри)  Добавил исходный пример http://jsfiddle.net/e1jvagkq/9/ только  картинки почему-то не подгружаются, не генерится src на основе ng-src

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
.imageBlock{
    width:100%;
}
.imageBlock img{
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-content imageBlock">   
    <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="/media/{{ block.image }}">                                    
</div>
```

у меня работает такой вариант:

```
<div class="panel-content">
   <div class="img-responsive">
      <img ng-src="/media/{{ block.image }}">
   </div>                                    
</div>
```

Comment: а что будет, если фото вертикальное? Например в Блок 2 (на картинке в вопросе) вставить вертикальную картинку.... Не получится ли она растянута на ширину?

Comment: да, она растянется, но это уже вариации на тему CSS max-width:100% например

Comment: @Dmitry у меня то же самое, блоки накладываются друг на друга. Проблема возникает именно при использовании заголовка, без него все работает и без дополнительных стилей.

Comment: @Emm а если обернуть панель в контейнер?

Comment: @Dmitry то есть? Будет  вот так? `<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
           <div> <div class="panel panel-default">              
                  ...
           </div></div>`    А что это даст?

Comment: @Emm контейнеру то надо стиль задать, по которому ангуляр будет расчитывать высоту

Comment: @Dmitry не совсем понимаю. Вы имеете в виду указать у обертки height 100% ? Angular-Gridster автоматически высчитывает высоту и ширину каждого блока, в зависимости от указанных пропорций (sizeX и sizeY). От размера содержимого самого блока (картинки, например), итоговый размер блока не зависит. Т.е. содержимое масштабируется пропорционально. Однако из-за картинки этот механизм сломался.

Comment: @Emm думаю что все-таки у обертки hight:auto, пусть ангуляр расчитывает высоту блока от обертки а не от панели